# Shopify - Partial SKU Search

Tags: search, shopify, sku

I'm wanting to be able to have the search functionality to be able to do the following

**Example Product SKU:** DPT10203

At the moment, if you search **DPT10203**, it will appear in the search results page with the product, but I'm wanting to be able to search for **10203** and have it search and match it to the characters in the SKU, and display on the search results.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Algolia Search](https://apps.shopify.com/algolia-search) app.

It will fetch you result with great speed and with most relevant and fuzzy search.